# Finding maximum value of group of rows POSTGRESQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Determine name, party and years served of the presidents with the most years of tenure in their
party. I can't use the join keyword.

Table president:

```
Name         | Party       | years_served|
-------------+-------------+-------------+
Roosevelt    | Democratic  | 12
Madison      | Demo-rep    | 8
Monroe       | Demo-rep    | 8
Adams        | Demo-rep    | 4
```

So the result would be Roosevelt, madison and monroe show up and adams doesn't because he didn't serve 8 years which is the max for demo-reps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`dense_rank()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) window function:

```
with cte as (
    select
        *, dense_rank() over(partition by Party order by years_served desc) as rnk
    from Table1
)
select
    Name, Party, years_served
from cte
where rnk = 1
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0326f/1)</kbd>**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT Name 
FROM President pr 
  INNER JOIN (SELECT Party, MAX(years_served) as YS FROM president GROUP BY Party) as MaxYS on MaxYS.Party=Pr.Party 
WHERE pr.years_served>=MaxYS.YS
```

Hope is what you are looking for.

Comment: I can't use the join keyword here

Comment: @wickys: why do you think you can't use a join there?

Comment: Can i ask why you can't?